# Repeated words error on the main site's FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-faq

[FAQ](https://security.stackexchange.com/faq) (There apparently are people who read this, *gasp*)

"IT Security - Stack Exchange is for **is for** Information Security..."

That's about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, good point -- that area needed a lot of cleanup.

I converted to simple, straight markdown and fixed that as well as a few other issues.